# Using a single Cipher object or two different objects for decrypt and encrypt operations?

Tags: java, cryptography, javacard

As you know, when we want to do cryptography operations using Java Cards, we must use `Cipher` objects. The question that I have is actually efficiency related. Let assume that I want to do some *Encryption* and *Decryption* operations using an AES key.

Which one of the following strategies is better?

1. Defining two different `Cipher` objects and initial them with a single key, but different modes (`MODE_ENCRYPT` and `MODE_DECRYPT`). Then for each operation I only need to call `doFinal()` method on the proper object.
2. Defining a single `Cipher` object and each time before calling `doFinal()` method do an `init()` method call on the object with proper mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, according to the documentation of `Cipher.doFinal(...)`:

> AES, DES, triple DES and Korean SEED algorithms in CBC mode reset the
>   initial vector(IV) to 0. The initial vector(IV) can be re-initialized
>   using the `init(Key, byte, byte[], short, short)` method.

It means that if you use AES-CBC with non-zero IV, you have to call `init` after each `doFinal`, so there is no choice, really.

---

Let's have a look now at some real-world measurements I did on my J2E145 cards by NXP.

Both `ALG_AES_BLOCK_128_CBC_NOPAD` and `ALG_AES_BLOCK_128_ECB_NOPAD` require **34 bytes of RAM** and **32 bytes of persistent memory** per  object instance.

Concerning time consumption, there are 4 possible situations:

**Situation 1:** the same transient key:

```
key1 = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES_TRANSIENT_DESELECT,
 KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
...
cipher.init(key1, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
cipher.init(key1, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
```

Result: **11 ms** per each `init(...)`

**Situation 2:** different transient keys:

```
key1 = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES_TRANSIENT_DESELECT,
     KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
key2 = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES_TRANSIENT_DESELECT,
     KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
...
cipher.init(key1, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
cipher.init(key2, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
```

Result: **18 ms** per each `init(...)`

**Situation 3:** the same persistent key:

```
key1 = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES,
 KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
...
cipher.init(key1, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
cipher.init(key1, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
```

Result: **12 ms** per each `init(...)`

**Situation 4:** different persistent keys:

```
key1 = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES,
     KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
key2 = (AESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES,
     KeyBuilder.LENGTH_AES_128, false);
...
cipher.init(key1, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);
cipher.init(key2, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
```

Result: **19 ms** per each `init(...)`

**Conclusion:** `init` is really fast independently of the memory type, because EEPROM is only read and copied into the internal (transient) memory of the `Cipher` instance. Although I can imagine some cases with high time consumption requirements, 34 RAM bytes seem to be too many to pay for 20ms. Exact results can be different on your platform, of course, but the trade-off efficiency will remain more or less the same.

Comment: Good erfforts opn the exact timings vojta! Still if you are using IV=0 you can benefit with persistent key data. I think thats a valid case...

Comment: I wonder if thats just a typo in you code lines that there is always only one `cipher` and not `cipher1`; `cipher2`?

Comment: @PaulBastian Yes, but you can gain round 20ms only... Is that enough for 34 bytes of RAM? I don't think so...

Comment: @PaulBastian No, that is not a typo... I measured "option 2" - how much time I need to perform `init(...)`

Comment: Depends how often you use it and what your preferences are :P

Comment: Due to RAM limitation, It is more rational (logical?) to use a single Cipher object instead of 3 or 6 different Cipher objects for asymmetric cryptography operations using 3 different RSA 2048 key pairs, . Am I right?

Comment: @EbraHim As Paul said, it depends on your preferences... However, RSA requires much more RAM than AES, so just one Cipher instance seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Your information is very useful but the conculusion is not. Surely it depends very much on the use case. I'd imagine for all high volume web servers that spending 34 bytes per thread on a Cipher is significantly worth the massive 20ms per call.

Comment: @mjaggard This is a Java Card question. The situation is quite different on less limited platforms, of course.

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you are handling with persistent or transient key material.
If you have persistent key material:

- Option 1 needs more EEPROM but you have a significant time boost because you call `init()` only once when key material is generated or imported.
- therefore Option 2 is not desirable

If you have transient key material:

- Option 1 needs more EEPROM and time boost is almost non-existent because you need to call `init()` anyway. I did some major testing 2years ago and if I remember correctly there is either none or a very tiny performance delta between the two options
- Option 2 needs less EEPROM and reduces complexity of the code, therefore its desirable